# Unable to send email from Command Line in Postfix (warning: TLS library .....)

Tags: postfix, smtp, centos7, saslauthd, starttls

I configured postfix with ssl/tls. and created an smtp. However I am unable to send test email and/or login.

"Text below first defines error log (different attempts) and then configuration files."

Error log on terminal.

```
[First Attempt]
[root@domain postfix]# telnet mail.example.org 587
Trying 139.59.182.62...
Connected to mail.example.org.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 example.org ESMTP Postfix
ehlo mail.example.org
250-example.org
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
starttls
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
ehlo mail.example.org
Connection closed by foreign host.

[Second Attempt]
[root@domain postfix]# telnet mail.example.org 587
Trying 139.59.182.62...
Connected to mail.example.org.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 example.org ESMTP Postfix
ehlo mail.example.org
250-example.org
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
auth plain
334
username
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: another step is needed in     authentication
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.

[Third Attempt]
[root@domain postfix]# telnet mail.example.org 587
Trying 139.59.182.62...
Connected to mail.example.org.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 example.org ESMTP Postfix
ehlo mail.example.org
250-example.org
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
MAIL FROM:<user@domain.org>
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO:<******@gmail.com>
454 4.7.1 <*******@gmail.com>: Relay access denied
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

/var/log/maillog file

```
Aug 26 19:55:11 example postfix/smtpd[22132]: connect from example.org[00.00.00.00]
Aug 26 19:55:22 example postfix/smtpd[22132]: warning: example.org[00.00.00.00]: SASL plain authentication failed: another step is needed in authentication
Aug 26 19:55:40 example postfix/smtpd[22132]: disconnect from example.org[00.00.00.00]
Aug 26 19:55:42 example postfix/smtpd[22132]: connect from example.org[00.00.00.00]
Aug 26 19:56:25 example postfix/smtpd[22132]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from example.org[00.00.00.00]: 454 4.7.1 <*******@gmail.com>: Relay access denied; from=<******@example.org> to=<*******@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail.domain.org>
Aug 26 19:56:30 example postfix/smtpd[22132]: disconnect from example.org[00.00.00.00]
Aug 26 19:59:50 example postfix/anvil[22134]: statistics: max connection rate 2/60s for (submission:00.00.00.00) at Aug 26 19:55:11
Aug 26 19:59:50 example postfix/anvil[22134]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (submission:00.00.00.00) at Aug 26 19:54:29
Aug 26 19:59:50 example postfix/anvil[22134]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Aug 26 19:54:29
```

Configuration files:

[main.cf]

```
 myorigin = domain1.org
 myhostname = domain2.org
 inet_protocols = all
 mydestination = mail.domain1.org, domain1
 relay_domains = domain2
 alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
 alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
 alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
 alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
 virtual_alias_domains = domain1.org domain2.org
 virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
 smtpd_use_tls = yes
 smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
 smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/ssl.key
 smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/ssl.crt
 smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/interm.crt
 smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
 smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
 smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
 smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
 smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
 tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
 smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
 smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
 smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
 smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
 smtpd_delay_reject = yes
 broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
 smtpd_recipient_restrictions =           reject_invalid_hostname,permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
    reject_unauth_destination,
    reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org,
    permit

 smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
    reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,
    reject_unknown_helo_hostname
 mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
 mailbox_size_limit = 0
 recipient_delimiter = +
 inet_interfaces = all
 smtp_tls_security_level = may
 smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
```

[master.cf]

```
 smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
 #smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       1       postscreen
 #smtpd     pass  -       -       n       -       -       smtpd
 #dnsblog   unix  -       -       n       -       0       dnsblog
 #tlsproxy  unix  -       -       n       -       0       tlsproxy
 submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
 #  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
 #  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
 #  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
 #  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
 #  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
 #  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
 #  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
 #  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
 #smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
 #  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps     
 #  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
 #  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
 #  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
 #  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
 #  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
 #  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
 #  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
 #  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```

if you need any details, please let me know. I am stuck at it. tried different ways, from different tutorials but didn't help much.

Answer (score 2):

Oh dear gods, don't attempt to negotiate TLS with `telnet`! You'd have to do the key exchange and all the other TLS functions by hand. That way lies madness. You're currently failing because `ehlo mail.example.org` is in no way an appropriate part of `starttls`.

If you want to test smtp starttls, use `openssl` specifically:
`openssl s_client -connect <server>:587 -starttls smtp`

Comment: Hi, I tried. but still get same. output > `http://pastebin.com/atU7NH08`